# Why are true headings followed above 73N in the northern hemisphere, whereas in the southern hemisphere the change is made at 60S?

Tags: navigation, fms, inertial-nav-system

The question is in regards to the asymmetry of the changeover latitudes and **NOT** about why it needs to be changed.

Comment: Southern tip of South America is about 60S

Comment: @expeditedescent I made that observation as well, but it doesn't seem like a consistent reason as the highest northern land mass extends to 83N.

Comment: Because there’s a lot more *airports* between 60N and 73N than between 60S and 73S?

Comment: At 65°S, wouldn't the pole be on the wrong side for certain longitudes? (as the South pole is at 64°S lat.).

Answer (score 17):

Earth's magnetic field is not symmetric north to south.  In particular,  the magnetic declination can get significantly larger at a given southern latitude than it does at the corresponding northern latitude.  This can be seen by looking at a world declination map:

[image]

Curves of a given declination reach much lower southern latitudes than they do northern latitudes.  For example, the highlighted curve is 40° west of north declination;  its southernmost point in the northern hemisphere is at about 75°N, but its northernmost point in the southern hemisphere is at 35°S (!).  Another way this manifests is that the [South Magnetic Pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Magnetic_Pole) is at a significantly lower latitude than the North Magnetic Pole (~65°S vs. ~85°N).

As to *why* the Earth's magnetic field is so asymmetric, that's a question for [Earth Science.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com).  My understanding is that you may not get a good answer over there either;  the behavior of Earth's magnetic field is complex and not fully understood.